# Can we use symbol in if statement in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, logical-operators

The user is asked to enter one of the following mathematical symbols:

> +, -, *, or /

Can someone tell me how I can use these symbols in an `if` statement? If not, how can I do this without using an `if` statement, like 1 for addition, 2 for multiplication, etc?

```
if(z==+){
     std::cout<<x<<"+"<<y<<" is "<<x+y;
   }
```

Comment: Make `z` of type `char`, and use `if (z == '+')`, perhaps?

Comment: Try ````if (z=='+')````. The plus sign is a character. And the user will enter a character. Like in: ````char z; std::cin >> z;````

Comment: Consider using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for such a task. Your question is very related to one of the examples there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user inputting a value will typically be inputted as a char or string(depending on how you are reading it in. You cannot just compare a variable to a + sign on its own, it instead do something like this:

```
if("+" == z) {
//do operation
}
else if("*" == z) {
//do operation
}
else {
//etc.
}
```

or use switches.

Comment: You should also give an example using character data type instead of strings.

Comment: The `switch` statement can't be used with strings. :-(

Comment: But a `switch` can be used with single characters

Answer (score 2):

You can store the symbol input in a char `char symbol`, then :

```
switch(symbol){
    case '+':
        std::cout << ... ;
        break;
    case '-':
        std::cout << ... ;
        break;
    ...

    default:
        std::cout << "symbol not valid\n"; ;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just enclose the operater in quotes and use a string/char datatype to store the operator

```
char z;
    if(z=='+'){
         std::cout<<x<<"+"<<y<<" is "<<x+y;
       }
```

Comment: I recommend adding spaces around operators, it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

`+` and `==` are operators. Their syntax expects two operands. `z` is a character. It cannot be compared with an operator, but only other variable. As other answers say, `'+'` becomes a character https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set and can be compared.

Answer (score 1):

If the symbols are inputs from user in cmd then they are of type char.

```
char z;
if (z == '+')
  std::cout << x << "+" << y << " is " << x + y;
```